# Template logic not working - Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

template

```
<form  method="post" action=".">
{% csrf_token %}
  <table  width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
   <tr>
   <td colspan="2" class="incident-type">
   {% for type in typeList%}
   {% if type.parent_type_id == None %} 
   <h1>{{type.title}}</h1>
   {% else %}
   {% if checked_ones  %}
   <label><input type="checkbox"  checked="True" value="{{ type.title }}" name="key">{{ type.title }}</label><br /> 
   {% else %}
   <label><input type="checkbox"  value="{{ type.title }}" name="key">{{ type.title }}</label><br /> 
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

see here,check box inputs are getting from this line in views.py

```
 checked_ones = [unicode(x) for x in subtype if unicode(x) in request.POST.getlist('key')]
```

The Problem here is,if any one of the option is checked and saved,all the other checkbox options are getting selected(after page redirect).

Tried with some logic loop,Need some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
{% for type in typeList%}
  {% if type.parent_type_id == None %} 
  <h1>{{type.title}}</h1>
  {% else %}
  {% if type.title in checked_ones %}
  <label><input type="checkbox"  checked="True" value="{{ type.title }}" name="key">{{ type.title }}</label><br /> 
  {% else %}
  <label><input type="checkbox"  value="{{ type.title }}" name="key">{{ type.title }}</label><br /> 
{% endif %}
 {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
```

Hope this helps!